# Iterate over an array of JSON objects with jsoncpp

Tags: arrays, json, c++11, jsoncpp

I have an array of JSON objects, jsonArr say, of the following kind:

```
[
  { "attr1" : "somevalue",
    "attr2" : "someothervalue"
  },
  { "attr1" : "yetanothervalue",
    "attr2" : "andsoon"
  },
  ...
]
```

Using jsoncpp, I'm trying to iterate through the array and check whether each object has a member `"attr1"`, in which case I would like to store the corresponding value in the vector `values`.

I have tried things like

```
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;
Json::FastWriter fastWriter;
reader.parse(jsonArr, root);

std::vector<std::string> values;

for (Json::Value::iterator it=root.begin(); it!=root.end(); ++it) {
  if (it->isMember(std::string("attr1"))) {
    values.push_back(fastWriter.write((*it)["uuid"]));
  }
}
```

but keep getting an error message

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Json::LogicError: in Json::Value::find(key, end, found): requires objectValue or nullValue
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pretty self explanatory:

```
for (Json::Value::ArrayIndex i = 0; i != root.size(); i++)
    if (root[i].isMember("attr1"))
        values.push_back(root[i]["attr1"].asString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to what @Sga suggested I would recommend using a ranged **for** loop:

```
for (auto el : root)
{
  if (el.isMember("attr1"))
    values.push_back(el["attr1"].asString());
}
```

I find this to be more readable plus it saves the extra call on `size()` as well as the index-wise retrieval.